# Python Spark: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: hive, pyspark

I have a .py file in PySpark as follows

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, SQLContext, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
iot = sc.textFile("file:///home/meter/df_final.csv")
iot  = iot.map(lambda p: p.split(","))
header = iot.first()
iot_f = iot.filter(lambda p:p != header)
iot_f = iot_f.map(lambda p: Row(DeviceImei = str(p[0]), DeviceTimeStamp = 
p[1], Avg_PF=float(p[2]),Sum_PF=float(p[3]),FRQ=int(p[4]),THDVL1=float(p[5]),T ,MachineName = str(p[16]),HUM = int(p[17]),OLI = int(p[18]),GridStatus = bool(p[19]))).toDF()

hc = HiveContext(sc)

iot_f.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("iot")
```

Now when I submit this job as `./bin/spark-submit --master yarn/path/to/file/file.py` I am getting an error as `non-keyword arg after keyword arg`

Where am I missing? I want a hive table created named as 'iot'.

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: finding error in line 20

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the error.

```
iot_f = iot_f.map(
          lambda p: Row(
              DeviceImei = str(p[0]), 
              DeviceTimeStamp = p[1], 
              Avg_PF=float(p[2]),
              Sum_PF=float(p[3]),
              FRQ=int(p[4]),
              THDVL1=float(p[5]),
              **T = int(p[6])** ,
              MachineName = str(p[7]),
              HUM = int(p[8]),
              OLI = int(p[9]),
              GridStatus = bool(p[10])
           )
      ).toDF()
```

It is now showing some other error which I shall figure out separately.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample code, you are passing the number of argument.

```
iot_f = iot_f.map(
          lambda p: Row(
              DeviceImei = str(p[0]), 
              DeviceTimeStamp = p[1], 
              Avg_PF=float(p[2]),
              Sum_PF=float(p[3]),
              FRQ=int(p[4]),
              THDVL1=float(p[5]),
              T,
              MachineName = str(p[7]),
              HUM = int(p[8]),
              OLI = int(p[9]),
              GridStatus = bool(p[10])
           )
      ).toDF()
```

Here you are missing value for argument `T` (`make it T = p[6]`), ie you are getting the exception.

In python whenever passing any number of arguments its mandatory that you need to pass positional argument first and then keyword arguments.

Here you are using `Row Class` so each argument should be of either keyword or positional.

If using both then positional must be first. like

```
iot_f = iot_f.map(
          lambda p: Row(
              str(p[0]), 
              p[1], 
              float(p[2]),
              Sum_PF=float(p[3]),
              FRQ=int(p[4]),
              THDVL1=float(p[5]),
              T = p[6],
              MachineName = str(p[7]),
              HUM = int(p[8]),
              OLI = int(p[9]),
              GridStatus = bool(p[10])
           )
      ).toDF()
```